# Can not send OAuth 2.0 token to google via Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, oauth-2.0, outlook, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update my Google Calendar from a desktop version of Outlook.  When I add an event to my outlook calendar, the following VBA code is executed:

```
Set httpCall = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Dim sURL As String
sURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<my google gmail account>/events?sendNotifications=false&fields=etag%2ChtmlLink%2Cid&pp=1&access_token=<my OAuth 2.0 client id>"
httpCall.Open "POST", sURL, False
httpCall.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
httpCall.Send Json
Dim sReturn As String
sReturn = httpCall.responseText
```

The value of sReturn at the end of executing the code is this:

[image]

I have an OAuth 2.0 client id and client secret but obviously, I dont have something set up correctly.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you need to pass an access token or other valid authentication credentials to get the job done. The code is not authorized.

You may find the [Google APIs](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/wiki/Google-APIs) and [Google Oauth2 VBA authentication](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/goavba/) pages helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write to a users calendar you need their permission.  Once you have their permission you should have an access token.  This access token must be sent as an authorization header along with your request.

```
hReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer cHBzX2NyZWdJIYXAhjhjdjsfhjdshakjfdhakfhjk5c0AjMTZAY3JlZ"
```

> I am trying to update my google cleandar

i recommend using [calendar.patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/patch) instead of calendar update.

Dont for get you need to authorize the user with the following scope

[image]

## Insert Event

While you have stated that you are trying to update your google calendar, from your code and the erro message it actually looks like you are trying to create a new event using [events.isnert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

If you are using this method remember it requires that you authorize the user with one of these scopes

[image]